# Convert the values given in an array into required interface properties in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-generics

Say that I have code like the following:

```js
const createFunction = (properties: string[]) => (obj: any) => {
  // do something with obj
};
```

However, this isn't currently typed very well. I'd like the following to work:

```js
const myFunction = createFunction(["a", "b"]);
myFunction({ a: 1 }); // <= no "b" property, so this line should error
```

How can I do this? I'm thinking that it's something to do with generics, but I can't quite get the syntax right. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The brief answer to that are [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types). The following is based on the approach taken in the [thi.ng/api](https://github.com/thi-ng/umbrella/blob/master/packages/api/src/api/keyval.ts) and [thi.ng/paths](https://github.com/thi-ng/umbrella/blob/master/packages/paths) libraries, which also include those kind of inferences for more deeply nested keys/values:

```
type Fn<A,T> = (a: A) => T;

function createFunction<T, A extends keyof T>(keys: [A]): Fn<Pick<T, A>, any>;
function createFunction<T, A extends keyof T, B extends keyof T>(keys: [A, B]): Fn<Pick<T, A | B>, any>;
function createFunction<T, A extends keyof T, B extends keyof T, C extends keyof T>(keys: [A, B, C]): Fn<Pick<T, A | B | C>, any>;
function createFunction<T>(keys: PropertyKey[]) {
    return (obj: any) => {
        // do something...
    };
};

interface Foo {
    a: number;
    b: string;
    c: any;
}

const foo = createFunction<Foo, "a", "b">(["a", "b"]);

foo({ a: 1, b: "1" }); // ok
foo({ b: "1" });       // error: `a` missing
foo({ b: 1 });         // error: `b` wrong type
foo({ c: 1 });         // error: `c` wrong key
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgdgHgIIBoAqA+KBeKAKADwC4okBKHLNAbgChaAzAVzgGNgBLAezilYCcIAQ2AQYLdt0RoUpKBAKi4AEwDOUANYQQXBlEx4tIVSQDaSALpkS8BAAUOrDQhmkMsoXBAY6zNpx4+QRExCQDpWSR5RQgVdSNdfVkAIWilNU1tRIMjEyhzFKsbRAcnF0ioAB8oZPcoT29fMKkg4VFxfylyuQV0+Ky9V1Te2IyEwdkAYTTR-p1BjENtPIKaqaLYEsdnVyjq1OrJuoafRmbAgTbQzp4XRdySO34uSH5QAGltUysoAG9aKCAqCCYBMfi8PBcABGACsSA0KNgsL8oABfOjo+gcOCifgMISsaAwLhcP4AoFCEhwJgAWyhEH4dCBUChJFUwH42IA5kygax4V4MfRWDx2VAGCScK0Qh1JLdiVxZAAiIRK5VQpWLUwqtVQJUaqx0RgkvAoylQACMslZeotSrRZGoUAA9M6oFwNMauKaWSQlXaHU7mYDXfJ+M9+CQAAZCKNQGkcVSqblen02i2B4PM0MMiPRqFxgDuzzgXKgoEgqZR-MtmazIbdua4kagUdYRZLZaMtCAA)

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve the need, we nee to use [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types), but also we need to understand how TypeScript does type inferencing. Lets start from the mapped type:

```
type ObWithProps<Props extends (readonly PropertyKey[] | PropertyKey[])> =  {
    [K in Props[number]]: unknown
}
```

Above is a type constructor, for a given type passed as `Props` will generate a map type which has all keys equals to `Props` array values. Exactly this - `[K in Props[number]]` is saying that every key of our new type will have a type of value in the `Props` array given as argument.

Testing the new type shows correct results:

```
// creates type A = {a: unknown, b: unknown}
type A = ObWithProps<["a", "b"]> 
// creates type B = {a: unknown, b: unknown, c: unknown}
type B = ObWithProps<["a", "b", "c"]>
```

Lets now combine this type constructor with the function:

```
const createFunction = <A extends (readonly PropertyKey[] | PropertyKey[])>(properties: A) 
=> (obj: ObWithProps<A>) => {
  // do something with obj
}
```

Function `createFunction` takes as argument element of type `A`, and generates a function which takes as argument type created by our type constructor `ObWithProps<A>`.

How it works now:

```
const myFunction = createFunction(['a', 'b']); 
myFunction({ a: 1, b: 1, c: 1 }); // ech nope, should be error but there is no ;(
```

So looks like something is wrong, `myFunction` is expecting very wide type `string[]`, and not our strict `['a','b']`. This is not an issue of our implementation, but this is how TS is inferencing, the inference is wide, as TS don't know if `['a','b']` has this shape just by example, or always. To tell the compiler that we work with persistent structure, we can or explicitly type it, or use [`as const`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions). Take a look on both solutions:

```
// using as const
const myFunction = createFunction(['a', 'b'] as const);
myFunction({ a: 1, b: 1, c: 1 }); // error as c is not allowed

// using explicit type
type T = ['a', 'b'];
const v: T = ['a', 'b'];
const myFunction = createFunction(v);
myFunction({ a: 1, b: 1, c: 1 }); // error as c is not allowed
```

### Edit - better inference without as const

As @jcalz mention in the comment, by pushing polymorphism up, TS compiler is able to inference type more exact. Consider the change:

```
const createFunction = <K extends PropertyKey, A extends K[]>
  (properties: A) => (obj: ObWithProps<A>) => {
  // do something with obj
}
```

The difference is in `<K extends PropertyKey, A extends K[]>`, we introduce additional generic argument `K` which enables to inference directly our keys.

---

To also clear this up. I am using `unknown` as we don't have requirement for a type of values of our results. We constrain only keys.

Hope it helps.

Comment: You can also do it [this way](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gRgdQJbABYAUBOB7MBnAHi1zyggA9gIA7AE1MwgENbtqAbEKYyTUAaQggA2gF0AfFAC8UAEoQAxtky0iOfMOoBXALZwImUQBooW6gGtq2AO7VxAKHtLqeYFAWMmVAGJmFwJDZpeygoAn4yShp6bnUDASETAEFIqjpSAApPVg4ufjEASnEMkNCoMDi+JAg8AC4oJNKC6UkM7DgAK3r4ZDQeQiTxZqlJAG9S0IB6SahWKDxsHQg0JGoAcyhrFFQodo7SgF9HZ1coHRBfan9A6ml3Tx8-ALYM4QByJjeTN7g30QKANz2c6Xa4vUZQJj1ACMUAOgKg0zImBwmBMcDOSDweFWa2BFyeNwyEKhUGh6PqACY4QikdhzEwQPjQc9qMTITCKVBKSYFPUAMw0gGImYGVG80zUCiQfwQWhAA) to convince the compiler to infer literal values without `as const`.